# Filling Two Vectors from F(x) Function

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, vector

I've got a question. Below is my code snippet where I am trying to fill a vector given a function yv. When I run the code, there is no error, but it does not print out a result, nor does it show the plot I want.

```
import matplotlib as plt
import numpy as np
import math as m

e = 2.17
sigma = 1
mu = 0
xv = np.linspace(-4, 4, 100)

for rows in range(0):
    for cols in range(100):
        yv = 1 / (sigma * (2 * m.pi) ** (-0.5)) * e ** (-0.5) * ((((xv - mu) / sigma)) ** 2)
        print('xv= {}'.format(xv))
        print('yv= {}'.format(yv))

        plt.plot(xv, yv, 'b-o', linewidth = 2, label = 'xv vs. yv')
        plt.show()
```

What am I missing?

Thanks again!
Brandon

Comment: `range(0)` produces no numbers.

Comment: Remove both lines with "range".  The purpose of NumPy's vectorization is that you don't need to run a Python loop.

Comment: @tom10 When I do that adjustment I get this following error... AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'plot'

Comment: @Brandon: `import matplotlib.pyplt as plt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your matplotlib import was not quite right. Try this:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math as m

e = 2.17
sigma = 1
mu = 0
xv = np.linspace(-4, 4, 100)

yv = 1/(sigma*(2*m.pi)**(-0.5))*e**(-0.5)*((((xv-mu)/sigma))**2)
print('xv= {}'.format(xv))
print('yv= {}'.format(yv))

plt.plot(xv, yv, 'b-o', linewidth=2, label='xv vs. yv')
plt.show()
```

Comment: This works! Thank you. Seems like sometimes its the things that are right in front of you that you don't see.